# Use Sql Join two times on a single table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

This is my query in 3 Nested form. What i want is to re-write this query using JOINS but the problem is same table is repeating two times as you can see.

```
$query = "
    SELECT
        *
    FROM userinfo
    WHERE id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            iduser
        FROM u_n_relation
        WHERE idnetwork IN (
            SELECT
                idnetwork
            FROM u_n_relation
            WHERE iduser = '$userid'
        )
    )
    AND virtual_name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
    ORDER BY id LIMIT 5
"
```

What i tried was this :

```
$query = "
    SELECT
        userinfo.*
    FROM userinfo
    INNER JOIN u_n_relation ON (u_n_relation.iduser = userinfo.id)
    WHERE 
        (userinfo.virtual_name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
        AND u_n_relation.iduser = '$iduser')
    ORDER BY userinfo.id LIMIT 5
"
```

But still not getting the correct result.
Can anyone please shed some light on how to do this?

Basically what the query says is :
Fetch the details of the users who have joined the networks you have joined.

Comment: please be more specific

Comment: Specific? I just want the JOIN form of the NESTED query.

Comment: both the queries have different WHERE clauses'. How do you expect them to give the same result?

Comment: I am already too confused thinking of two tables. Can you please help me?

Comment: Use table aliases to make your query easier to read and to distinguish between the two joins to the same table. Such as: `userinfo u INNER JOIN u_n_relation ur1 ON (ur1.iduser=u.id) INNER JOIN u_n_relation ur2 ON (ur2.idnetwork=u.idnetwork)`

Answer (score 1):

`select distinct` is not needed when you use `in`.  However, it may be needed when you use `join`.  Otherwise you can turn the `in`s into inner joins:

```
SELECT ui.*
FROM userinfo ui JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT unr.iduser
      FROM u_n_relation unr JOIN
           u_n_relation unr2
           ON unr.idnetwork = unr2.idnetwork and
              unr2.iduser = '$userid'
      WHERE unr.virtual_name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') 
     ) unr 
     ON ui.id = unr.iduser
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, Mark L. is correct in that aliases are the key to JOINing the same table multiple times in a query.

Secondly, holy crap formatting. Formatting is especially important when posting your query to ask a question about it.  Your formatting caused Gordon L. to mis-read which table the "virtual_name" field was in.

Initially your first query didn't make sense to me but jackkorbins comment got me to view it again and I get it this time - here it is formatted more read-ably:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
   userinfo 
WHERE 
   id IN (-- This sub-query returns *any* iduser that is a member
          -- of those same networks
          SELECT DISTINCT 
             iduser 
          FROM 
             u_n_relation 
          WHERE 
             idnetwork IN (-- This sub-query returns the multiple networks
                           -- that have $userid as a member
                           SELECT 
                              idnetwork 
                           FROM 
                              u_n_relation 
                           WHERE 
                              iduser = '$userid')) 

   AND virtual_name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') 
ORDER BY 
   id 
LIMIT 5
```

So another way to make a JOIN version of that query would look like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   ui.*
FROM 
   u_n_relation unr

   INNER JOIN u_n_relation net
      ON (net.idnetwork=unr.idnetwork) 

   INNER JOIN userinfo ui
      on ( ui.id = net.iduser )

WHERE 
   unr.iduser = '$iduser'

   and ui.virtual_name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') 
ORDER BY 
   ui.id 
LIMIT 5
```

Sorry for my earlier confusion. :-)

Comment: I think you mistook the first query and then went the whole way wrong. SELECT * 
FROM 
   userinfo 
WHERE 
   id IN .. Now this will return multiple ids.

Comment: @jackkorbin - The part you missed was in the sub queries - where he "selected a distinct iduser" after supplying the value as '$iduser' .. if you supply one value .. and select distinct on it .. you get .. one value.

Comment: @jackkorbin - Ah! I now see what you were getting at, yes I was fixated on the userid being entered and returned in the select. :-)